# how can i stop excel showing 'number stored as text' for numbers with commas, when running R program?

Tags: r, openxlsx

I'm running this R code and the excel output file shows 'number stored as text' warning boxes against each of the numbers. I'm aware it's the commas causing this, but i want the commas in there.

Is there a way to stop these warning boxes showing?

```
df1 <- data.frame(col_1 = c('1,000', '1,500', '5,000'))

wb <- createWorkbook()
sheet.name <- 'test'
addWorksheet(wb, sheet.name)

writeData(wb, sheet = sheet.name, df1)
saveWorkbook(wb, file = "Test.xlsx")
```

Comment: Which packages are you using? Please always add them in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just save the numbers without the comma and then set the option to display a comma in Excel. You have the values as character string---not as numeric---in R. I don't think you can save them with a comma and simultaneously have it as number.

However, you can remove the comma in R before the export and set an additional style option to have the commas in Excel:

```
require("openxlsx")
df1 <- data.frame(col_1 = c("1,000", "1,500", "5,000"))

df1[, 1] <- as.numeric(gsub(",", "", df1[, 1]))
wb <- createWorkbook()
sheet.name <- 'test'
addWorksheet(wb, sheet.name)

writeData(wb, sheet = sheet.name, df1)

comma_thousand <- createStyle(numFmt = "COMMA")
addStyle(wb, sheet = sheet.name, style = comma_thousand, cols = 1, rows = seq(2, nrow(df1) + 1))
saveWorkbook(wb, file = "Test.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```

I have the rows as `seq(2, nrow(df1) + 1)` since you have a header in the table.

Here, `df1[, 1] <- as.numeric(gsub(",", "", df1[, 1]))` is used to get rid of the commas before you save the dataframe as xlsy. You could also use other functions. In Rstudio, your dataframe will look like these before and after running this line:

[image: Before and after removing commas]

The output looks like this in Excel:

[image: Excel with commas]

So basically, use the values with the commas in R (for whatever reason), but remove them before you save the xlsx and use the code I provided in order to tell Excel you want the values to be displayed with commas.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for the help. I wasn't even aware the comma style existed.